# User activation via email does not work when system status is "off"

Tags: emails, activation, token

- System Status is set to *off*
- Create a new user, with permissions to *Access the site when the system is off* and *Access the CP*

As long as the system is off, the activation email sent to the user is broken, and instead goes to the "Service Unavailable" page.

Is this by design? It seems like if those specific permissions are granted when creating the user, they should still be able to activate.

Comment: Hey Tim, per Brad's answer, it looks like this was considered a bug and has been fixed. Since this issue is about to disappear, and will no longer be historically relevant, I'm gonna close this thread as a "bug report".

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed on the upcoming Craft 2.3 release such that if the system status is set to *off*, account verification and set/forgot password logic will still run.